# Is there a good way to test deep link in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links, deeplink, uitest

Since UITest runner is run in a separate runtime with app, I'm using Safari to test deep link.
And I also tried iMessage.

But the more test cases added, the more test time took. 
So I want the other way to test deep link, and it moves to right ViewController.

Is there a good way to test deep link?
Somebody help me‍♀️